# Getting multiple arrays into AJAX from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**EDIT**

[image]

I need to get two fetched arrays into one array, and use `echo json_encode` to send it back to `AJAX`.

Here is my PHP code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$arr = array();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$id_logged = $_SESSION['login_id'];



$date1 = $_POST['current_year'];

    //$res = array();
    $c = "cash";
    $i = "installment";
    //SUM of cash paid Month
    $sql = "SELECT 
    count(app_id) as patients, 
    t.m as month 
FROM (    
   SELECT 1 AS m UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
   SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION
   SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) AS t
LEFT JOIN dentist.appointment ON t.m = month(date_app) AND
          id_logged = :logged AND year(date_app) = :year_now
GROUP BY t.m";
$sqlStmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sqlStmt->bindValue(":logged", $id_logged);
$sqlStmt->bindValue(":year_now", $date1);
$exec = $sqlStmt->execute();
$res1 = $sqlStmt->fetchAll();

$sql2 = "SELECT 
    count(app_id)+1 as patients, 
    t.m as month 
FROM (    
   SELECT 1 AS m UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
   SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION
   SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) AS t
LEFT JOIN dentist.appointment ON t.m = month(date_app) AND
          id_logged = :logged AND year(date_app) = :year_now
GROUP BY t.m";
$sqlStmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
$sqlStmt2->bindValue(":logged", $id_logged);
$sqlStmt2->bindValue(":year_now", $date1);
$exec2 = $sqlStmt2->execute();
$res2 = $sqlStmt2->fetchAll();

$res['one']=$res1;
$res['two']=$res2;

echo json_encode($res);
```

And here the response at XHR:

[image]

[image]

Now at the AJAX script, I need to get each part of the array so I can display it on a chart:

```
success:function(res)
{
  var patientData = [];
  $.each(res, function( key, row)
  {
    patientData.push(row['one']);
    console.log(patientData);
  });
  //Bar Chart Script;
 }
```

But I can't see any data at the console, nor at the bar chart. The result of the console is `undefined`:

[image]

Comment: patientData.push(row);  <- try this

Comment: Yeah and how I access the first array ? `patientData['one']` or `patientData[0]`

Comment: patientData[0]. As you have pushed the rows into patientData which is an array

Comment: If you see at the PHP, when I was working with only single array that I am sending that inside a variable `AS 'patients'` and in AJAX, I am getting them as `push(row['patients'])`. Now When I am sending 2 arrays, how should I write them ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it:

```
    success: function(data){
        var patientData = [];
        var res = $.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(res, function(index, element) {
            alert(res[index]);
            patientData.push(res[index]);
        });
    }
```

Comment: the `alert[row[0]]` gave me `alert [object][object]` and `alert[res[0]]` gave me `alert undefined`

Comment: you can't use res[0] outside the '$.each' loop, try patientData[0] instead

Comment: If you see at the PHP, when I was working with only single array that I am sending that inside a variable `AS 'patients'` and in AJAX, I am getting them as `push(row['patients'])`. Now When I am sending 2 arrays, how should I write them ?

Comment: The same way you did before,in PHP put the the two arrays which you want to return in one array then pass it through json_encode and return it, in the Ajax success function you will have the same result and you don't need to change anything but this time patientData will be an object so to access it you have to use patientData[0][0]

Answer (score 1):

You will get key("one", "two", ...) in `key` and row data in `row`

> As $.each returns object property name(`key`) in first parameter and property `value` in second parameter so here we go as follow:

```
success:function(res){
  var res = $.parseJSON(res);
  console.log(res);
  var patientData = [];

  $.each(res, function (key, row){
    patientData.push(row);
    console.log(patientData);
  });
  //Bar Chart Script;
}
```

For example we can check the result like this

```js
$.each({"one":[1, 2, 3, 4], "two":[5, 6, 7, 8]}, function (key, value){
  console.log(key, value);
  
  /* write to document */
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("Key:" + key);
  document.write(", Value:" + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As you defined `patientData` in `success` so you won't be able to access it outside this function; if you are trying to do so just saying ;)

Comment: If you see at the PHP, when I was working with only single array that I am sending that inside a variable `AS 'patients'` and in AJAX, I am getting them as `push(row['patients'])`. Now When I am sending 2 arrays, how should I write them ?

Comment: @androidnation do you want to merge all records in single array?

Comment: No. I want to display the 2 arrays on the same chart

Comment: FYI, `$.parseJSON` is giving me an error on VM:4, so I think working without it is better

Comment: May you share your chart code and also share error you are getting on VM:4

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
success:function(res)
{
  var res = $.parseJSON(res);
  console.log(res);
  var patientData = [];
  $.each(res, function (key, row)
  {
    patientData.push(row.one);
    console.log(patientData);
  });
  //Bar Chart Script;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah and how I access the first array ? `patientData['one']` or `patientData[0]`

Comment: Check the modified answer $.each(res, function(key, row){ ...});

Comment: the modified code gave me at the console `undefined`

Comment: Are getting output in console.log(res); ??

Comment: I am getting the array `console.log(res)`

Comment: If you see at the PHP, when I was working with only single array that I am sending that inside a variable `AS 'patients'` and in AJAX, I am getting them as `push(row['patients'])`. Now When I am sending 2 arrays, how should I write them ?